# Error when trying to access OneDrive root from UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, onedrive

When I run the following code I receive exception (message: Must be authenticated to use '/drive' syntax) on invoking the request:

```
private async Task<Item> GetRoot()
{
    var driveClient = 
        await OneDriveClientExtensions.GetAuthenticatedUniversalClient(
            new string[] { "files.readwrite", "offline_access" }
            );

    if (!driveClient.IsAuthenticated) return null;

    var itemRequest = driveClient.Drive.Root.Request();

    return await itemRequest.GetAsync();
}
```

I tried to debug using override for `IHttpProvider` and I see GET request is sent to https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root with two headers `X-RequestStats` and `Authorization` with correct token.

I also checked consent for the app in https://account.live.com/consent/Manage and I see "Access OneDrive files" and "Access your info anytime" permissions.

I probably miss something basic. Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also checked consent for the app in https://account.live.com/consent/Manage and I see "Access OneDrive files" and "Access your info anytime" permissions.

This is a **documentation issue**, the files.* scopes are not properly registered for OneDrive Personal.

[The document](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm) has been **reverted** to previous version, please use the **onedrive.readwrite** scope to ensure your app works as expected.

See [this issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/369) in onedrive-api-docs repository

> It appears that the files.* scopes are not properly registered for OneDrive Personal. I've reverted the documentation to indicate you should use the onedrive.* scopes for OneDrive Personal. Please use the onedrive.readwrite scope to ensure your app works as expected.